# How to use different Views in RecycleView

Tags: android, header, android-recyclerview

I want to use different view's in RecycleView like on image.
[image]

1 View I use once in RecycleView, other view's like 2,3,4,5 on image.
**What do you can recommend for me?**

Comment: Use StaggeredGridLayoutManager!

Comment: @tinysunlight Thanks. If you write shrot example code or write link I accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link:

https://github.com/cundong/HeaderAndFooterRecyclerView.

You can add a `header` and use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.